# Excel formula for calculating Unix time stamp

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that will convert a date and time into a unix timestamp. I suppose a logical starting point could be in the format of the result of =NOW() i.e. 25/10/2021 15:26 or the result thereof split into two cells for convenience but I'm not quite sure about how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please show some example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Something like: `=TEXT(NOW()-DATE(1970,1,1),"[ss]")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Unix time stamp is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970, we can simple take the date we want, subtract 1/1/1970 and multiply by the number of seconds in a day:

```
=(NOW()-"1/1/1970")*60*60*24
```

[image]

Comment: Yup. Maybe a good 2nd option would be to just calculate `=NOW()-"1/1970"` and custom number format the value as `[ss]`. It would be a completely different value to calculate any further.

Comment: Thank you, simple and elegant :)